# Ä, Ö and Å do not display correctly on django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a template that has scandinavian letters in my app built on Django and Google App Engine. However, I'm having difficulties displaying those characters correctly. Here's the simplified problem:

In my urls.py I have the following code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'index.html'
    }),)
```

For example letter "ä" turns to appear as "ÃÂ¤" although I have the following line in the template file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

I have also tried to set FILE_CHARSET and DEFAULT_CHARSET to 'utf-8' although it should be the default.

The template (that does not actually contain any {{}} or {% %} ) is displayed normally if I navigate to the file itself in the browser.

What's wrong? Why the scandinavian characters are not displayed correctly?

EDIT:
Apparently there were something wrong with the file encoding. I cannot exactly point what was the key but now everything is fixed. The file encoding changed (possibly after reboot of the server) after which I could just find & replace the broken letters.

Comment: IIRC, the HTTP `Content-Type` header takes priority over the `<meta>` tag, so check that the `Content-Type` returned with your page looks correct.

Comment: it displaying correctly on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, modifying the charset settings and booting the app resulted to change in encoding. Then broken letters were visible and they could be fixed manually.